# Capitalization of “Recht”/“Unrecht” in “Du hast Recht/Unrecht”

Tags: capitalization

I think I’ve seen *Recht/Unrecht* both being capitalized and not capitalized:

> (a) Du hast Recht.
>
> (b) Du hast recht.
>
> (c) Du hast Unrecht.
>
> (d) Du hast unrecht.

The non-capitalized version doesn’t seem to be supported by the [dictionary](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/unrecht). Is it actually correct or not?

Comment: http://www.korrekturen.de/kurz_erklaert/recht_haben_oder_recht_haben.shtml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All four versions are correct. However the lower case ones are recommended by the Duden so you’d probably rather go with them.

Sources:

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/recht_haben

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Unrecht

Comment: It is quite illogical to use "recht" in lowercase in "Recht haben". It is obviously a noun there (eg Recht haben, Angst haben, Spaß haben) and nouns should be written in uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

The only correct pre-reform spelling was lowercase. This is still considered correct (recommended, even), although you may also capitalize *Recht* now. Duden has more: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/recht

Comment: "recht und Ordnung" !? Absolut nicht. Recht als Nomen wurde immer groß geschrieben.

Comment: Ja, natürrlich. Es geht nur um "recht haben" udgl.

Comment: Dann solltest du vielleicht spezifizieren, dass du dich auf recht als Adjektiv beziehst. Ansonsten ist "The only correct..." nämlich falsch.

Comment: Nichts für ungut, aber das Ausgangsbeispiel war "Du hast Recht". Dafür gilt das Gesagte uneingeschränkt.

Answer (score 1):

Even if all forms are correct, I prefer the uppercase.

Due **Recht** is mostly used as a noun.

> Mit deiner Handlung bist du im Recht.

Literally means, that your behavior fits to the law. Law is an object and therefore written uppercase in habit.

But there are also usages of **Recht** in which it is not used as a subject or object and lowercase is more adequate.

> „Was hältst du von Pizza heute Abend?“
>   „Ja, das ist mir recht“

Person2 agrees to Person1s suggestion. **recht** is an adjective here which represent the state of Person2s opinion to the suggestion.

If you don’t know if to write something upper- or lowercase, always question if the word is a subject/object. If that, it’s **always** written uppercase.

But pay attention, we got a saying here in Germany:

> Die wichtigste Regel der deutschen Sprache ist die, dass es **immer** Ausnahmen gibt.
>       (The most basic rule in German is, that there are always exceptions.)